# adding multiple small panels to a frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

i am trying to make a simple interface in java,but i have a problem with adding multiple panels into a frame.I want it to be a cafe software so there will be multiple tables.Here is my code

```
public class CafeView extends JFrame{

private JButton takeMoneyBtn = new JButton("Hesabı Al");

public CafeView(){
    JPanel table1 = new JPanel();
    this.setSize(800,600);
    this.setLocation(600, 200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);

    table1.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 150);
    table1.setLayout(null);
    this.add(table1);
    table1.add(takeMoneyBtn);

}
}
```

When i run it, i just see an empty frame.In this code i just tried to add one simple panel,if i can do it i can add others too i think.So how can i solve it and add small and many panels into a frame,what am i missing? Thank you for your help.(There isn't a main method cause i call this interface class from another class.)

Comment: Maybe your frame isn't empty at all. Try adding a border to your panels using setBorder() so you can actually see the JPanel.

Comment: Also it is wrong to call setVisible(true) before you are done putting all of your visual components together

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're arranging the position of your component which is in this case `JPanel` using `.setBounds(..,..)` , You should instead use it to the top level container (`JFrame`, `JWindow`, `JDialog`, or `JApplet`.) not to `JPanel`.
So remove :

```
table1.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 150);
```

We are provided by `LayoutManager` to arrange components, see [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

```
   public class CafeView extends JFrame{

private JButton takeMoneyBtn = new JButton("Hesabı Al");

public CafeView(){
    JPanel table1 = new JPanel();
    this.setSize(800,600);
    this.setLocation(600, 200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);

   //table1.setBounds(100, 100, 150, 150);
    //table1.setLayout(null);
    this.add(table1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    table1.add(takeMoneyBtn);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a LayoutManager to place all the controls and access the content pane directly. [How to use FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

```
public class CafeView extends JFrame{

private JButton takeMoneyBtn = new JButton("Hesabı Al");

public CafeView(){
    JPanel table1 = new JPanel();
    this.setSize(800,600);
    this.setLocation(600, 200);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container c = this.getContentPanel();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    c.add(table1);
    c.add(takeMoneyBtn);
    //c.add() more stuff..

    this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1.  Further note.  Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.